# Change color of uitableviewcell 'delete' section when in editing mode in iOS7

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

I feel like this is a bit of a daft question but I can't work it out. I have a uitableview which displays sub-classed uitableviewcells. When I swipe to enable editing mode I would like to change the red color that appears to a different shade of red. Am I able to do this?

I have tried changing background colors or adding subviews when

```
-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

is called but I can't make any thing happen to the 'delete' section only to the main cell. I also added a subview to self.editingaccessoryview in initWithCoder and I still couldn't make anything happen.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also facing this same problem and finally i had overcome it. See this given answer

[Highlighted color problem of cell is solved in IOS-7 in this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117161/cannot-show-delete-button-on-tableviewcell-ios-7/19160869#19160869)

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are setting cell setBackgroundImage for Cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath (Delegate Method). Do not set this here. Set your image in:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellList.png"]]; }
```